# Create a Function with a loop structgure that returns Smith as htimS. Using a loop structure. For pl/sql on Oracle Application

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION letter_reverse
   (char_string IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   v_rev_stg  VARCHAR2 := 'htimS';
BEGIN
  LOOP 
    rev_stg := SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'h',5) || SUBSTR(rev_stg, 't',4) || SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'i',3) ||SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'm',2) || SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'S',1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Error at line 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

```
5. BEGIN
6.   LOOP 
7.     rev_stg := SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'h',5) || SUBSTR(rev_stg, 't',4) || SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'i',3) ||SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'm',2) || SUBSTR(rev_stg, 'S',1);
8.   END LOOP;
9. END;
```

Comment: What is a question ? A side note:, there is an endless loop in your function, it never ends.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a function, why hard code those values?. A general function can be as follows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION letter_reverse
   (char_string IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   v_rev_stg  VARCHAR2(20) := NULL;

BEGIN
  for i in reverse 1..length(char_string)   --loop through the length of string backwards.
    LOOP
      v_rev_stg := v_rev_stg||SUBSTR(char_string,i,1) ; -- append elements to v_rev_stg
  END LOOP;

  RETURN v_rev_stg;
END;
```

/

```
select letter_reverse('Smith') reversed FROM DUAL;
REVERSED
--------
htimS
```

**Note:**  Oracle does have a `REVERSE` function that is undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for your consideration:

```
DECLARE
   l_string   VARCHAR2 (100) := '?taerg LQS/LP t''nsI';
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (
         UTL_RAW.reverse (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (l_string))));
END;
```